# get the selected data from a record that was made through join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to get data of the column 'role' from a pulled record that was made through a join (refer below)

```
$user = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_details', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
})
->get();

$user_role = strtolower($user->role);
```

but it gives me this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

any help, ideas, clues?

Comment: Instead of establishing the relationship this way, you should instead use the proper belongsTo and hasMany relationships in the model.

Comment: yeah, im planning on it but this is my current build and I have not much time to re route it at this moment as I'm trying to catch unto this project timeline, ill make sure I'm going to use that proper eloqouent belongings later after I fix this. So any ideas from the issue above?

Answer (score 0):

ah I use **->first()** instead of ->get().